# No password specified

Tags: java, spring-integration

I am trying to get access to a gmail account using  `integration`. I am required to use `Http.inboundGateway`. So add to the line like

```
.from(Mail.imapIdleAdapter("imaps://"+(Http.inboundGateway(String.format("%s:%s@imap.gmail.com/INBOX", "myEmail", "myPassword"))).toString())
```

but the problem is, in the run time it complains that

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no password specified?
```

As you can see, i have already define my password in my request, but it cannot recognize it, also i am sure pass is true

Here is the complete code:

```
@Bean                  
    IntegrationFlow processInvoiceFlow() {
      return IntegrationFlows
          .from(Mail.imapIdleAdapter("imaps://"+(Http.inboundGateway(String.format("%s:%s@imap.gmail.com/INBOX", "myEmail", "myPassword"))).toString())
                .selectorExpression("subject matches '.*invoice.*'"))
          .transform("@invoiceProcessor.extractInvoice(payload)")
          .route("#xpath(payload, '//total <= 1800', 'string')", mapping -> mapping
              .subFlowMapping("true", sf -> sf
                  .handle("invoiceProcessor", "processInvoice"))
              .subFlowMapping("false", sf -> sf
                  .handle(System.out::println))
          )
          .get();
    }
```

The point is that, i have access to the account without `Http.inboundGateway`
using:

```
.from(Mail.imapIdleAdapter(String.format("imaps://%s:%s@imap.gmail.com/INBOX", myEmail, myPassword))
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you mind to explain:

> I am required to use Http.inboundGateway

?

From other side what is the strange code to call `Http.inboundGateway().toString()`...

What exactly do you want to reach with that code? Yes, it is valid by Java nature. But it is absurd by the logic...

Your `Mail.imapIdleAdapter(String.format())` looks much better!